# which one is the correct way of converting String to ByteString?

Tags: string, haskell

I found the following two functions that convert `String` to `ByteString`, which one is the correct way? And what's the difference?

[Data.ByteString.Char8.pack](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.2/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:pack)

[Data.ByteString.UTF8.fromString](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string-1.0.1.1/docs/Data-ByteString-UTF8.html#v:fromString)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Data.ByteString.Char8.pack` will mangle any non-ASCII characters. *All* of the functions in that module assume that a "character" is exactly 8 bits. That works just fine for plain ASCII, but breaks horrifically for other valid Unicode characters. Generally, you should probably just avoid this whole module.

Really, `ByteString` is intended for *binary* data. (I.e., if you want to read data from a file, leaving it unchanged.) If you want to deal with *text*, you should probably use the `text` package, rather than `ByteString` itself. The `text` package then has functions for encoding or decoding `ByteString` data using different character encodings (typically UTF8).

In summary, the "correct" way to turn a Unicode `String` into binary data depends which character encoding you want.

Comment: "If you want to deal with text, you should probably use the text package, rather than ByteString itself." Unfortunately not always an option - for example, program code is arguably text, but the `OpenGL` package wants bytestrings for shader code (because that's what the C backend expects).

Answer (score 5):

I generally use [encodeUtf8](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.3.0/docs/Data-Text-Encoding.html#g:5) from `text`.

I think the `utf8-string` function you link will also handle all of Unicode correctly.  I'm not familiar with the package, I just took a quick look.

`Data.ByteString.Char8.pack` explicitly does not handle Unicode code points above 255, so it's only correct if you know your `String` is limited to that range.